# Angular JS declare controller using data retrieved from PHP file

Tags: php, database, angularjs, controller

I have a controller declared and I was loading the data from a json file. THat was working fine, so I decided to create a database and a php file to do a select and retrieve the data from the table I am storing it.

**The data from php is retrieved on json, this is my code on php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "peopledir");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM people");
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}

print json_encode($rows);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**It retrieves this:**

[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Santiago","name":"Santiago"}]

**My controller is:**

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var myApp = angular.module('myApp');


myApp.controller('PeopleController', function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://localhost').success(function(data) {
    $scope.peoples = data;
  });

});
```

But it is not showing any data on the frontend.

To be clear, if I paste the data to a json file, exactly as php is showing it, I can see the user Santiago on the page, but with above code, reading directly from `http://localhost`, I can not see anything.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc):

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```